# Confused - Need guidance

Tags: practical-islam

I've written six Gartner reviews

(Of IT products that I worked on) the truth is I've not utilized IT products 100% but had utilized up to some extent.

& earned $150.Then $100 from my end + $150 from the reviews, I had purchased the course.

Now my thought or question is - Whatever I did right or wrong.

Guide me.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is simple.
If you did say lies, or you said something which you really did not know, then you did a wrong thing.
it is easy to find out. just use Imam Ali(A) (4rth khalifah) techniqe:

> Treat everyone, like you want to be treated.

> فَأَحْبِبْ لِغَیْرِکَ مَا تُحِبُّ لِنَفْسِکَ وَ اکْرَهْ لَهُ مَا تَکْرَهُ لَهَا

(nahjolbalaghe)